# Insert specific character after each instance of a character in a line

Tags: substitute

I would like to insert a specific character after each instance of another character in a line. For example, inserting a '\' after each instance of another '\' on a line.

So, from this: `C:folder\folder2\folder3\folder4`, 
to this:`C:folder\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4`

I was thinking it may be a variation on the `s` command, but I haven't found anything that works yet. Or maybe using search and replace is a better way.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, the `s` command does just fine: `:s/\\/\\\\/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extending the comment of @guillem

you need a simple `:s/\\/\\\\/g` for each line that you want to perform the substitution on. Or maybe visually select the lines and then `:'<,'>s/\\/\\\\/g`

Here, you need to escape each `\` with another `\` before it.

**Edit**: I'm adding [a link to vim substitution command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_and_Replace). Moreover, vim's substitute command `:s/<pattern>/<change>/` is the same as the `search and replace` command. Look at the wiki page for using vim's substitute command.

Comment: Why not `:s-\-\\-g` to avoid all the escapes? The delimiter is pretty flexible.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Um, that's because I didn't know it. I'll edit my answer after I read about it a little, ok?

Comment: Fair enough! Just a suggestion

Comment: I saw the deal about `substitute delimiters`. And you, sir, made my day.

Comment: Aren't all the escapes needed to escape the escape character itself (the backslash) and not the delimiter (the forward slash)?

Comment: @brhfl Yeah, you're right. I don't know why, maybe cause in linux, filesystem uses `/`, not `\`. So, maybe I thought OP wanted `/` to be changed into `//`. I removed my last edit. Thank you.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Care to comment on comment from @brhfl?

Comment: Vimgolf: `:s/\\/&&/g`

Comment: @EnanAjmain yea the escapes here are necessary because its escape a back slash; i was overeager and mixed up `/` and `\`